# Not able to connect with mongodb in Laravel 5.2

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.2, I am trying to connect with mongodb. I have followed the steps mentioned in https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb . After creating a table in migration when I run the command 'php artisan migrate', I get an error

**[MongoConnectionException]

  Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on database 'admin' with username 'admin': auth failed**

The Migration file looks like this, just created it with artisan:

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
  */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string("username")->unique();
        $table->string("password");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

 /**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function down()
   {
       Schema::drop('users');
   }
}
```

---

```
db config:

 'mongodb' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '*****'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'admin'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'admin'),
        'options' => array(
            'db' => env('DB_AUTH_DATABASE', '') // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
        )
    ),
```

And the used versions:

```
"require": {
      "php": ">=5.5.9",
      "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
      "jenssegers/mongodb": "^2.2"
   },
```

Could someone help me how to resolve this issue

Comment: Are you using the right username and password?

Comment: yes I have added the username and password

Comment: Have you added `DB_AUTH_DATABASE`in `.env`? And have you created the database you are using?

Comment: After providing DB_AUTH_DATABASE in .env file I got this error 
 [MongoConnectionException]                                                   
  Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on database '*****' with username 'admin': auth failed

Comment: Have you created the database(*****) you are using, laravel only can use a database that exists.

Comment: yes I have created a database in mongodb and provided the details in .env file too